# jquery scroll with timeout

Tags: jquery, scroll, settimeout

I set up timeout with jquery at scroll action. For example, after scroll wait 10 seconds and send ajax request, but how to cancel previous timeout if receive new action of scroll withing first timeout not processed?

Comment: I think is better if you split your question in two different ones.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [`clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearTimeout):

```
var timer;

$(window).scroll(function(){

    if ( timer ) clearTimeout(timer);

    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        // Make your AJAX request here...
    }, 10000);
});
```