# jQuery scroll calls a function multiple times

Tags: jquery, scroll, window

I have a jquery scroll function as below :

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if (($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) >= ($('body').height() * 0.7)) {
        alert('call me');
     }
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<div style="height:450px;">BOX</div>
```

When I scroll, instead of just one `call me` I am getting multiple times `call me`. Why so and whats wrong ?
[JSFiddle Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/f3C6Y/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a feature not a bug, is normal to receive it each time the scroll event happens, the scroll event is launched every time the position of an element within the scrollbars is changed.

You can add a flag, a class or a timeout to avoid it if don't want it.

For example with a timeout you may do it like this:

### JS:

```
var timeout;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if(typeof timeout == "number") {
      window.clearTimeout(timeout);
      delete timeout;
   }
   timeout = window.setTimeout( check, 100);
});

function check(){
if (($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) >= ($('body').height() * 0.7)) {
        alert('Call me!')
     }
}
```

The fiddle is here :
http://jsfiddle.net/f3C6Y/2/

Comment: in short, this is infact using a debounce

Comment: Yes, this is a denouncing mechanism

Answer (score 2):

There may be other ways to do this, but you could set a CSS class once its called then check if that class exists before you try to call it again... Something like this:

```
function callfunction() 
{
    if (($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) >= ($('body').height() * 0.7)) {
    $('body').addClass('called');
    alert('call me');
    }
}

$(document).scroll(function () { 
    if(!$('body').hasClass('called')) 
    {
        callfunction();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

a timer is bad, it creates a lot of programming overhead... adding classes makes the code slow as well. You're binding a function and doing a check for a parameter every time the user scrolls. That's a HUGE waste of resources!

if you want to call a function ONCE on the user scrolling unbind the function at the first call:

```
function callfunction(){
   $(window).unbind("scroll");
   //*... do the rest of your programming here
}
```

Comment: I wonder why nobody voted this up, this seems the correct and efficient way. thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice and clean(er) solution on Stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10573021/jquery-scroll-with-timeout)

```
var timer;

$(window).scroll(function(){

    if ( timer ) clearTimeout(timer);

    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        // Make your AJAX request here...
    }, 10000);
});
```