# jQuery scroll function append with previous values?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q8k28cad/)

On first click values `1 to 10` are push to the array then scroll the container alerts the value at one time.On second click values `1 to 10  and 1 to 10` are push to the array then scroll the container alert the value at two time. On thrid click `1 to 10 , 1 to 10  and 1 to 10` are push to the array, but on scroll it alerts the three times. I need pass the last value into the scroll function therfore alerts the only one time. How can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Try this](https://jsfiddle.net/q8k28cad/3/)

Use the `unbind` for your problem.  From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20493351/jquery-scroll-calls-a-function-multiple-times). alert is launched at a every scrolling. so use `unbind` or consider the time and set the flag.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But your script not display value on continuous scrolling  at the same click. Like i click the h4 tag into two time, then scroll the container it alerts, but when i tried to scroll another time in the same click but it not give the alert. Because your condition is goes to wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're registering a new scroll event handler each time; that said, you can simply register it only once and have it access the `array` variable from within the event handler, like so:

```js
var array = [];

$('h4').click(function(){
  for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    array.push(i+" ");
  }
});

$("#container").scroll(function () {
  if (array.length) {
    alert(array);
  }
});
```

```css
#container {
  width:100%; 
  height:200px; 
  overflow:scroll;
}
#ele {
  width:2000px; 
  height:200px;  
  background:#2a2a2a;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="ele"></div>
</div>
<h4> click </h4>
```